# Are the hooks in the dashboard such as "load-$page_slug$" and "admin-head-$page_slug$" reliable and consistent throughout installs?

Tags: actions

I've created a page using `add_theme_page` with the name of `access_page`. Whenever someone accesses that page, or rather, for that page, a few hooks are created, such as `admin-head-access_page` and `load-access_page`.

Are these hooks guaranteed to be consistent everywhere, on every install?

Comment: Why wouldn’t they be?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I understand this could be a stupid question, but I was working with the `rest_url` and that changes depending on your "reading" settings, something I could never have known, just asking if they're consistent given all of WP's default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, if I get your question correctly, but...

Yes, these hooks are native WP hooks:

- [admin head-(page hook)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head-(page_hook))
- [load-(page)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page))

So if you create such page on given WP instance (for example you create it with your plugin/theme and that plugin/theme is active on that instance), then these hooks will get fired.

Of course if such page is not added on given WP instance, then that action won't get fired... (But how could it - if there is no such page, then it can't be displayed, then no actions will be run while it's requested).

I hope it answered your question.